# Continuity of $f(x)= x\cos 1/x$ when $x\neq 0$, and $0$ otherwise

Tags: calculus, continuity

Is the following function continous on $\mathbb R$?

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\begin{align} &x\cos \frac 1x &  x\neq 0 \\ 
&0 & x=0 \end{align}\end{cases}$

I tried to derive it and show the limit from both 0+ and 0- are 0 but I get to infinity plus infinity and such expressions.

This is the derivative: $\frac 1x\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$

Maybe this function isn't continous at all ?

Comment: If you want to check continuity, why do you differentiate?

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmm if the function has a derivative at a point its continuous.

Comment: Yes, but a lot of functions are continuous but don't have a derivative. Continuity is a much weaker condition.

Comment: Ah I see, I made it much more complicated than it should.

Comment: @DanielFischer other than bounding it like was done by user, what other ways are there to show it ? Probably taking limits of both sides of the original function. Can it be done with Haine in some way ?

Comment: Bounding the difference $\lvert f(x) - f(a)\rvert$ is the most direct way. That may sometimes be easier to do one side at a time, but not much. Generally, you use the usual theorems (sums, products, compositions etc. of continuous functions are continuous) when you can, and at special points like $0$ here, you have to estimate the difference. I don't see any useful other way than what user did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is well known, that
$$\left|\cos{a}\right|\leq 1$$
for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Thus, the following holds:
$$\left|x\cos{1/x}\right|\leq \left|x\right|\cdot\left|\cos{1/x}\right| \leq\left|x\right|\cdot 1 = \left|x\right|$$
Thus
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0 = f(0) $$

which means that $f$ is continous at $x=0$

Comment: So simple. Thanks.

Comment: Why the two bars?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane just a "TeX"-issue. I made an edit to my answer :)

Comment: How do you prove that inequality ?

Comment: @Senishoshitsu I made an edit. I hope it's more clear now.